# jquery plugin for a div stop on a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create similar on this on this website

http://www.bombardier.com/en/aerospace/business-aircraft.html

when you scroll a links stops on a certain point then when you click any of the link, it goes on the target div and while you scroll it, the link goes active when scroll on the target div.

Is there a jquery plugin for that?

Thanks!

Comment: No. you can achive by simple javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mo15aLs3/)

```
            <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="">
                <li id="menu-item-14" class=" menu-item-14"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-15" class=" menu-item-15"><a href="#Mission">Mission</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-16" class=" menu-item-16 active"><a href="#service">Services</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-17" class=" menu-item-17"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-18" class=" menu-item-18"><a href="#community">community</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="" id="About">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.  
            </div>
            <div class="" id="Mission">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            <div class="" id="service">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div class="" id="team">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
            <div class="" id="community">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>


            <script>
            $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
                var id = $(this).attr('href');
                var $id = $(id);
                if ($id.size() === 0) {
                    return;
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                var pos = $(id).offset().top;
                pos = pos-95;   
                $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
            });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi use below code to do this:

HTML

This will act as menu

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="scroll-bottom" data-scrolltarget="#target_div_id1">section 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="scroll-bottom" data-scrolltarget="#target_div_id2">section 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="scroll-bottom" data-scrolltarget="#target_div_id3">section 2</a>
```

This is your Container div

```
<div id="target_div_id1"> ....Section 1 Description...  </div>
<div id="target_div_id2"> ....Section 2 Description...  </div>
<div id="target_div_id3"> ....Section 3 Description...  </div>
```

Now add a Magic JQuery Code

```
$(".scroll-bottom").click(function() {
    var toid = $(this).data('scrolltarget');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(toid).offset().top - 45
    }, 1000);
});
```

I hope this works

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try this :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a plugin, just jquery.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Not sure why I was downvoted. Here is an example. It's the simplest answer.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szLf4dbt/)